# Wireshark to monitor IIS Outgoing traffic

Tags: iis, wireshark

Newbie question

In the attached screenshot I am trying to see all outgoing traffic from my local IIS to a web service with the text "ibservices" in it. I couldn't find where to put the "ibservices" filter text though.

[image]

Comment: More of a ServerFault question. https://www.wireshark.org/docs/man-pages/wireshark-filter.html Wireshark allows you to define URL filters.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

http contains ibservices

This does the trick